# Meaning of :: in Java syntax

Tags: java, syntax, java-8

What is the meaning of **::** in the following code?

```
Set<String> set = people.stream()
                        .map(Person::getName)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is method reference. Added in Java 8.

`TreeSet::new` refers to the default constructor of `TreeSet`.

In general `A::B` refers to method `B` in class `A`.

Comment: +1, what will they think of next? String switching perhaps... Interfaces with methods...

Comment: @Bathsheba, I'm crossing my fingers for operator overloading.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Especially if they also define `,` as an operator.

Comment: @Bathsheba Default and Static methods are available in Interfaces since 1.8

Answer (score 38):

`::` is called Method Reference. It is basically a reference to a single method. i.e. it refers to an existing method by name.

`Method reference using ::` is a **convenience** operator.

Method reference is one of the features belonging to [Java lambda expressions](http://javapapers.com/core-java/lambda-expression-in-java-8/). Method reference can be expressed using the usual lambda expression syntax format using `–>` In order to make it more simple `::` operator can be used.

Example:

```
public class MethodReferenceExample {
    void close() {
        System.out.println("Close.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MethodReferenceExample referenceObj = new MethodReferenceExample();
        try (AutoCloseable ac = referenceObj::close) {
        }
    }
}
```

## So, In your example:

```
Set<String> set = people.stream()
                        .map(Person::getName)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Is calling/creating a 'new' treeset.

A similar example of a Contstructor Reference is:

```
class Zoo {
    private List animalList;
    public Zoo(List animalList) {
        this.animalList = animalList;
        System.out.println("Zoo created.");
    }
}

interface ZooFactory {
    Zoo getZoo(List animals);
}

public class ConstructorReferenceExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //following commented line is lambda expression equivalent
        //ZooFactory zooFactory = (List animalList)-> {return new Zoo(animalList);};    
        ZooFactory zooFactory = Zoo::new;
        System.out.println("Ok");       
        Zoo zoo = zooFactory.getZoo(new ArrayList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Person::getName in this context is shorthand for `(Person p) -> p.getName()`

See more examples and a detailed explanations in [JLS section 15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13-500)